# Tracking user activity AWS backend - data used for AI/ML

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, artificial-intelligence, backend, tracking

Started working on a marketplace application and we are looking to intensely track user activity, store it in some DB so that the Data/AI team can use it later to model better recommendations. We want to track every request as well as other things such as a user expanding a description or stopping at a certain point (presumably interested in that item).

The format of how we store the data hasn't yet been decide on but it will be something standard and easy to query on a user level for the AI model.

**What do you recommend for the backend:**

- Own Lambda function -> call to Db to store data
- AWS Glue
- AWS CloudTrail
- Other service and why

**What do you recommend for the database:**

- Some SQL
- DynamoDb
- CassandraDb
- Other database and why

Comment: You'll need your own back-end to capture and store the events -- Glue is for transformations, CloudTrail captures API calls to AWS but not your own app. Frankly, it is easiest to store the raw 'events' in S3 and then process it with Athena or Spark. It's also much cheaper than running a database. One option is to stream the events to Amazon Kinesis Firehose, which will persist the events in S3 as 'chunks' based on time period or volume of data.  You can then read the data from S3 for later processing.